# Inserting a value into table from a user Form

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a user form that is adding data into a Worksheet this just looks at the first column and adds a new entry at the bottom of this column.

However on another tab I have data that builds a graph however if new data is added to the bottom of the table the graph wont pick up the new entry, even if I expand the data labels of the graph. It works however if I insert a new row in the table.

So I have tried writing some code that first inserts a new row then should added the data from the userform in the next empty cell however it just adds the data at the bottom.

I've added my code below. If anyone can help that would be great.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim NextRow As Long
 Dim NextRow2 As Long


 NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
    CountA(Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Range("A:A")) + 1
 NextRow2 = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
    CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1


  If ProjectManager.Text = "Helena Healy" Then
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Row("3:3").Insert
  End If

   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 1) = projectid.Text
   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 2) = WBScode.Text
   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 3) = ProjectDes.Text
   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 5) = ProjectManager.Text
   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 4) = Building.Text
   Worksheets("Tracker Sheet").Cells(NextRow, 7) = ProjectSponsor.Text

   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRow2, 1) = projectid.Text

 End Sub
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7JBm.png)

-

[After Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9neZ4.png)

unfortunately I can only add two images so I've put what it currently starts as and what it should look like after. This is currently not what is happening project 23 is going to the bottom in cell A25

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRow2+1, 1) = projectid.Text`?

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: post some examples of before, after-no good and after-good scenarios

Comment: I can only add two links as I don't have high enough rep so I've put before and how it should be

Comment: the two links looks the same!

Comment: Instead of using `NextRow`, just use `3` because you inserted a blank row at row 3, so put the data there.  If preferred you can sort the data after it has been added to the sheet.